# How to rotate a texture in SDL2?

Tags: c, rotation, sdl-2

Is there an easy way to rotate a texture in **SDL2** and **C**, a function or a parametre that I missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDL2 is very poorly documentated so I had hard time finding it but SDL_RenderCopyEx does the job.

Source : http://www.ginkgobitter.org/sdl/?SDL_RenderCopyEx